# Kotlin android highscore combing all instances of score into highscore

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to achive the following:

[image]

If you can't see the picture I am basically trying to get the instances of each point gained into another list that combines the total points and lists them according to user

This is as far as I got

```
private lateinit var recyclerviewFrag : RecyclerView
private lateinit var kotlinPointsData: ArrayList<KotlinPointsData>

              kotlinPointsData.sortBy {
              pointsData -> pointsData.totalpoints
                //if(pointsData.username.duple)
            }
val highscoreList = kotlinPointsData.groupBy { it.username}.forEach{points as
}




recyclerviewFrag.adapter = PointsKotlinAdapter(kotlinPointsData)
```

Comment: `achieve the following` achieve what ? can you please write an explanation of your problem

Comment: The picture is kinda the explanation I dunno how else to explain it I am trying to basically make mutiple instances of a scores into a combained highscore

Comment: a lot of people can't see images, some companies block images based on firewall settings, etc, so usually just helps to get more answers if you write what you're trying to achieve, one of the reasons why questions with code as images get downvoted. also, images can be open to interpretation, hard to answer a question you can't explain yourself :)

Comment: There I added an explanation incase the picture can't be seen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your diagram, you have a username, with a point

```kotlin
data class User(val username: String, val points: Int)
```

You then want to create a new list containing the user along with the sum of all user points

```kotlin
data class TotalPointsUser(val totalPoint: Int, val user: User)
```

```kotlin
// list of users and their points
val users = listOf(
    User("1", 10),
    User("2", 7),
    User("3", 9),
    User("4", 7),
    User("5", 7),
    User("6", 9),
    User("7", 8),
)

// get sum of all points
val totalPoints: Int = users.sumOf { user: User -> user.points }

// create a new list with each user and the total points
val usersAndPoints: List<TotalPointsUser> = users.map { user: User -> TotalPointsUser(totalPoints, user) }
```

Comment: YES that last part what I was wondering about // get sum of all points
val totalPoints: Int = users.sumOf { user: User -> user.points }

// create a new list with each user and the total points
val usersAndPoints: List<TotalPointsUser> = users.map { user: User -> TotalPointsUser(totalPoints, user) }